# Open bash and run command on npm start

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

When I start my app, I do it by running `npm start`. Right now, `npm start` only runs my `server.js`. Is it possible to have `npm start` open a new bash prompt and run e.g. `grunt watch` to start the task that watches my less/stylus etc?

It would be nice to not have to manually start the `watch` task each time.

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify a custom start script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js & grunt watch"
}
```

https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html

Comment: I can't get this to work. Using a `|` and not `&` seems to work, though both processes run in the same bash window, and I only see output from on of the processes.

Comment: How about "node server.js && grunt watch"?

Comment: @Ben That would wait for the first command to finish, which doesn't happen unless it is killed manually.